# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to translate a block of D3 v4 code over to v3. Here is the block of code that is giving me trouble.

```
//var spiral = d3.radialLine()
var spiral = d3.svg.line.radial() 
  //.curve(d3.curveCardinal)
  .curve(d3.line.curve())
  //.curve(d3.curve.linear) 
  .angle(theta)
  .radius(radius);
```

The first line I commented out referencing the `radialLine` I was able to get around, however, when trying to translate `d3.curveCardinal` to `d3.line.curve()` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined

I tried a few derivatives of `d3.line.curve()` but to no avail. Does anyone know a way I can translate this successfully?

Comment: I think you are missing something related with your imports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#shapes-d3-shape):

> The *line*.interpolate and *area*.interpolate methods have been replaced with [*line*.curve](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_curve) and [*area*.curve](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#area_curve). Curves are implemented using the [curve interface](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#custom-curves) rather than as a function that returns an SVG path data string

For your backport this means to replace

```
.curve(d3.curveCardinal)
```

with

```
.interpolate("cardinal")
```

The whole statement thus becomes:

```
var spiral = d3.svg.line.radial() 
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .angle(theta)
  .radius(radius);
```

The v3 API docs have all the details on the correct usage of [`d3.svg.line.radial()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#line_radial) and its [interpolation modes](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#line_interpolate).